# I made a game where blocks fall and you have to dodge it but can't get the hitboxes right

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, collision

The hitbox seems to be on the left side of the cube, so it feels like the game is ending without me even hitting anything. I want to make it that the hitbox is exactly on the red rectangle, so that it's obvious that the black rectangle had hit you.

the up and down controls are just for future movement option if needed.

here's the code

```
import pygame as pg,pygame
import random
import sys

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 800

# Positions, sizes

SPEED = 10

MIDDLE = [500, 400]

score = 0

player_size = 90
player_pos = [WIDTH/2, HEIGHT-2*player_size]
playerX_move = 0
playerY_move = 0

enemy_size = 50
enemy_pos = [random.randint(0,WIDTH - enemy_size), 30] 
enemy_list = [enemy_pos]

# Colors

WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
GREY = [25, 25, 25]
BLUE = [65,105,225]
BLACK = [0,0,0]
GREEN = [65,255,105]
RED = [255,0,0]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

game_over = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
    delay = random.random()
    if len(enemy_list) < 10 and delay < 0.1:
        x_pos = random.randint(0,WIDTH-enemy_size)
        y_pos = 30
        enemy_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])

def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
    for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK, (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1], enemy_size, enemy_size))

def update_enemy_positions(enemy_list, score):
    for idx, enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
        if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < HEIGHT:
            enemy_pos[1] += SPEED
        else:
            enemy_list.pop(idx)
            score += 1
    return score

def collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
    for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
        if detect_collision(enemy_pos, player_pos):
            return True
    return False

def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):
    p_x = player_pos[0]
    p_y = player_pos[1]

    e_x = enemy_pos[0]
    e_y = enemy_pos[1]

    if (e_x >= p_x and e_x < (p_x + player_size)) or (p_x >= e_x and p_x < (e_x+enemy_size)):
        if (e_y >= p_y and e_y < (p_y + player_size)) or (p_y >= e_y and p_y < (e_y+enemy_size)):
            return True
    return False

while not game_over:

    player_pos[0] += playerX_move
    player_pos[1] += playerY_move

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    playerX_move = -5

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_move = 5

                # if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                #   playerY_move = -5

                # if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                #   playerY_move = 5

                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    playerX_move = -15

                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    playerX_move = 15

                # if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                #   playerY_move = -15

                # if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                #   playerY_move = 15

                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    print("SPACE")

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerX_move = 0
                playerY_move = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerX_move = 0
                playerY_move = 0

    screen.fill(BLACK)


    drop_enemies(enemy_list)
    score = update_enemy_positions(enemy_list,score)

    if collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
        game_over = True
    draw_enemies(enemy_list)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], 90, 90))

    clock.tick(30)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a list of `pygame.Rect`s instead of a List with the positions of your enemies. This would also allow  you to use `pygame.Rect.colliderect()` instead of your `detect_collision` function.
 I've also linked the [Pygame Docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).